# What are the remedies for land sickness?

Tags: air-travel, health, tips-and-tricks

I suffer from [land sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal_de_debarquement) after flying and it usually lasts around 2 weeks for me. Does anyone have any tips or tricks to prevent this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should see a doctor.

Comment: I don't see why this should be closed. It's clearly travel-related and, while we certainly can't give medical advice, I see no reason why we can't give tips on how to reduce or cope with symptoms. The condition seems quite rare, so maybe nobody will know an answer but that's not a reason to close, either.

Comment: [Health SE](http://health.stackexchange.com/) might be a really good fit for this one.

Comment: It's a good question for the site. Sure we're not physicians, but someone with a great tip may be along - - suggest keeping it open for a while.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is the same thing (or perhaps not) but I would get delayed 'air sickness' which would only kick in a couple of hours after I'd landed after a flight.

At first I wasn't sure if it was related to nerves about flying, but it didn't really dissipate the more I flew and got used to travelling.

I tried hyoscine tablets in the end, and they seemed to work. I was lucky in that I found a clinic [selling them](https://www.treated.com/travel-sickness/kwells) that meant I didn't have to go to the GP every time I wanted them. But whether these work for you, or are even available in your country is another matter.

As someone has previously said, I would approach your doctor for help if I were you, especially as 2 weeks is a long time to suffer.

Answer (score 3):

Ginger is a very effective antidote to motion sickness; perhaps it will help with your "land sickness," whatever that is... at least it won't do any harm. Get a fresh ginger tuber, make a thin slice, and tuck it in your mouth, between your teeth & cheek. You could also try ginger candies, altho I can't vouch for their effectiveness as I can for fresh ginger. 
On the other hand, if your "land sickness" is a kind of vertigo, ginger won't help. Vertigo happens when a tiny, tiny bit of calcification in the semicircular canals in your inner ear brushes against the nerve hairs and confuses your poor brain so it doesn't know which end is up. Awful feeling! Not unusual for it to be kicked off by air travel. It usually goes away in a few days. There is a set of exercises that consist of rotating your head into various positions, to sequester the speck where it can't bother you. Probably easy to find online, or ask an ENT specialist.

Comment: While ginger is, indeed, helpful for motion sickness/nausea,

Comment: Any actual evidence of what you said other than anecdotal?

Answer (score 3):

Land sickness is related to problems with the brain (not the inner ear or vestivular system), getting readjusted to being in land after a flight. The brain gets "stuck" with the sensation of movement. 
There is no cure for this, and motion sickness medicines does not help. Keep yourself hydrated, and if at rest your symptoms get worse, ironically, doing some excercise, walking or driving may help. In most cases, symotoms subside after a day or two. If not, consult a neurologist. In very extreme cases, Valium helps to mute the symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

1. Getting extra rest or sleep would help.  Drink a lot of water. This
   helps me most of the times.
2. I even take ginger lemon and honey in warm water to help me feel better.
3. I avoid taking medicines. They make me feel heavy after few hours of sleep.
4. I have heard about Acupressure-point wrist bracelets. I haven't used them but it seems they work perfectly by applying needed pressure on the wrist.
5. I tend to eat very light food while the travel. Eating a lot causes me a land sickness for a longer time. Try eating less and less spicy food.